# Is the text provided to a wildcard query analyzed?

Tags: elasticsearch

I plan to use wildcard queries on analyzed text fields using asciifolding (to get rid of french accents) and lowercase.

My first tests show e.g.
matches for `"wildcard": { "ar_titre.raw": { "value": "nomme*" } }` but no matches for `"wildcard": { "ar_titre.raw": { "value": "nommé*" } }`

Does that mean that when using wildcard (or prefix) queries, the text provided to `"value"` is not analyzed ? Or Is that a bug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`wildcard` queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) are term-level queries.

As explained in the official documentation, the wildcard expression is **not analyzed**:

> Matches documents that have fields matching a wildcard expression (not analyzed).